# Running MYSQL command inside a shell script not working

Tags: mysql, django, linux, shell, mariadb

I am trying to run a shell script with commands to run the Django Server.

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --name db_name -d mariadb

docker exec -it container_name mysql -u root -proot -e "create database db_name CHARACTER SET UTF8;  CREATE USER invuser@XXX.17.0.3 IDENTIFIED BY 'root1234$'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name .* TO invuser@XXX.17.0.3 IDENTIFIED BY 'root1234$';"

#mysql -u root -proot -e "create database db_name CHARACTER SET UTF8;  CREATE USER invuser@XXX.17.0.3 IDENTIFIED BY 'root1234$'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name .* TO invuser@XXX.17.0.3 IDENTIFIED BY 'root1234$'"


echo "Docker image name will be $1"

python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate

docker build . -t $1
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 $1
```

In this script, When I am trying to run :

```
docker exec -it container_name mysql -u root -proot -e "create database db_name CHARACTER SET UTF8;  CREATE USER invuser@XXX.17.0.3 IDENTIFIED BY 'root1234$'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name .* TO invuser@XXX.17.0.3 IDENTIFIED BY 'root1234$';"
```

I am getting this error :

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

OR when I run :

```
mysql -u root -proot -e "create database db_name CHARACTER SET UTF8;  CREATE USER invuser@XXX.17.0.3 IDENTIFIED BY 'root1234$'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name .* TO invuser@XXX.17.0.3 IDENTIFIED BY 'root1234$'"
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.17.0.2' (115)
```

But when I run this command out of the script, manually, It is working as expected and creating the database too and user too.

Can someone please suggest a better way to implement this via script?
I am using Centos 7 btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `docker exec` is being executed before the container is fully initialized.

Its better to use the full range of container arguments to initialize the database and avoid the need to `docker exec`:

```
docker run -d --name db_name \
    -e MARIADB_DATABASE=db_name \
    -e MARIADB_USER=invuser \
    -e MARIADB_PASSWORD='root1234$' \
    mariadb
```

If you want a `invuser@XXX.17.0.3` user strictly you can put `RENAME USER invuser@'%' TO invuser@'XXX.17.0.3'` in a `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/rename.sql` sql file passed in by volume.

To wait until the server is started up:

```
cid=db_name
waiting=${DOCKER_LIBRARY_START_TIMEOUT:-10}
echo "waiting to start..."
while [ $waiting -gt 0 ]
do
    (( waiting-- ))
    sleep 1
    if ! docker exec -i $cid mysql -h localhost --protocol tcp -P 3306 -e 'select 1' 2>&1 | fgrep "Can't connect" > /dev/null
    then
        break
    fi
done
if [ $waiting -eq 0 ]
then
    echo 'timeout'
    exit 1
fi
```

This will loop until a TCP connection is available.

source: [mariadb container test script](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/.test/run.sh).

Hopefully [MDEV-25434 HEALTHCHECK](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25434) will get included sometime to make this process simpler.